# How do I copy multiple lines of content from the web to one cell in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to copy multiple lines of content from a website to a single cell in excel. For some reason when I paste the information into excel it locates the first line in the cell I want and the rest in cells below the one I want.

Comment: Does the text have tab characters in it?

Comment: Have you tried any other form of pasting, like text only?

Answer (score 0):

Click the cell you want to paste into and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to go into edit mode. Then paste your text. This should make sure all the lines of text stay in that one cell.